# Passwordless Sign in with firebase without link sent to email

Tags: firebase

I'm working on a system that works similarly to whatsapp web. The idea is that a user is logged in with his account via firebase on his phone. And then he wants to do a fast sign in (maybe a 10 minute session) on a computer. So I read that a passwordless sign in was possible sending a link to the users email. Is it possible to generate this link (generate it somehow) on the phone (without sending it to the email). Thanks to this, the user on the computer could for example read a QR code generated on the phone with the passwordless sign in.
Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

The user needs to somehow identify himself and the way passwordless signin works is by using the email authentication.

It needs some form of unique ID. You can either use his email or his phone number. AFAIK Firebase has an authentication via SMS too.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add Passwordless registration and authentication to your Firebase project using [www.ownid.com](https://www.ownid.com)

It works with a QR code on Desktop, the UX is very neat.

Just follow [this documentation](https://docs.ownid.com/Integrations/firebase) and you can have it ready in minutes.